Felm regression not running in R
I was previously able to run the following regression but suddenly it does not work. After trying to run it, the stop sign appears in RStudio and nothing happens. I have a total of 300 000 observations.
master<- read_csv("hemo_final_oikeesti.csv", skip = 1)

#Sample Brand Intense dummy == 1, percentile = 10%
INTENSE <- master$`Brand Intensive`
master_all_intense <- filter(master, INTENSE == 1)

CIK_all_intense <- master_all_intense$CIK
BV_all_intense <-  master_all_intense$`BF US or G Dummy`
BVG_all_intense <- master_all_intense$`BF G Dummy`
SIZE_all_intense <- master_all_intense$`Log of mkt cap, t-2`
MOM_all_intense <- master_all_intense$MOM...35
BM_all_intense <- master_all_intense$`Log of BTM`
PRICE_all_intense <- master_all_intense$`log close price t-2`
DVOL_all_intense <- master_all_intense$`Log of VOL t-2`
YIELD_all_intense <- master_all_intense$`total dividend per share of LTM to current stock price`
ASSTGROWTH_all_intense <- master_all_intense$`Asset Growth`
ROE_all_intense <- master_all_intense$ROE
LEVERAGE_all_intense <- master_all_intense$LEVERAGE
RETURN_all_intense <- master_all_intense$`Monthly Return`
MONTH_all_intense <- master_all_intense$Month
YEARMONTH_all_intense <- master_all_intense$Year_Month
SIC_all_intense <- master_all_intense$`2-dig SIC`
ADSPEND_all_intense <- master_all_intense$`Log of Ad spend`
RDSPEND_all_intense <- master_all_intense$`Log of R&D`
ORGCAP_all_intense <- master_all_intense$`Log of Org Cap`
HIGHINT_all_intense <- master_all_intense$`High INT Dummy`
PROFITABILITY_all_intense <- master_all_intense$`Cash based operating profitability`

theregression3_all_intense <- felm(RETURN_all_intense ~ BV_all_intense  + SIZE_all_intense + MOM_all_intense + BM_all_intense  + DVOL_all_intense + YIELD_all_intense + ASSTGROWTH_all_intense  + LEVERAGE_all_intense + PROFITABILITY_all_intense| 0 | YEARMONTH_all_intense + CIK_all_intense )
summary(theregression3_all_intense)

I am running RStudio 2023.12.0+369 (2023.12.0+369), Mac OS X 2020 M1 Macbook Pro.

"the stop sign appears in RStudio and nothing happens" It means that your computer is in the process of executing your command.
